# Context switching in for loop

Tags: java, multithreading

I've the following java code. Will there be any "context switching" occuring during its execution?

```
Collection<MyBusinessClass> myCollection = getMyCollection();//has 1000 items

for (MyBusinessClass item : myCollection) {
 new Thread(() -> {                   
                   MyLongRunningTask();
                }).start();
```

Thanks.

Comment: There is **always** *context switching* going on, even in single-threaded programs, at least on Windows. Even if code only uses one thread, there is no guarantee that the thread isn't switched between multiple CPUs.

Comment: FWIW, any time you think you want to create new `Thread` instances in a loop, that's a sign that you should think about using a _[thread pool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html)_ instead.  Your code snippet is going to create a thousand threads all at once.  Does your computer have a thousand cores?

Comment: ...Even when they're sitting idle, waiting for a CPU to run on, each one of those threads will be using a significant chunk of memory for its call stack...

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have enough cores to host all the 1000 threads (+ 1 main briefly) + whatever few threads JVM needs like GC and finalizer, your threads *will have to share cores*. And hence *context switches will occur*. I am assuming here that `MyLongRunningTask` actually runs for a sufficiently long time for all of them to be still active by the time your last ones are spawned, otherwise probably the required number of available cores is a bit lower.

We can try to concoct a scenario how the scheduler actually runs ALL tasks *sequentially*, never 'overlapping', by having very short tasks (or a fairly crazy scheduler) so you can get away with a small number of CPU cores. But that seems off the point.